# Explain Cordova project + angularJS, phonegap project, ngcordova

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-build, ngcordova

I'm confused about these technologies. Actually i want to build a mobile application with SQLite database for offline as well as should support webApi services or something. So it should support both SQLite and server which targets IOS, Android and windows.

I did some R&D and gather some knowledge about cordova and angular.

I like to use angular on my mobile application so that i can manage my client side data and app flow easily and  wisely.

Now i'm confused whether to use cordova or phonegap or ngcordova (which i recently came to know that it exists).

As i mentioned, i want a mobile app with SQLite and support webApi services and also should support multiple platforms.

So now where/how to start and which is best one for me. i'm developing this app for production i mean real time app.

please help to start with.

This is my email id jprasanth74@gmail.com if you have any guide please share it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova is use for create build in different platforms

you have to start write code in angular.js

just use this sample link

```
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/
```

to create first app and send me your email i will send you the startup guide line to create enviroment with cordova and ionic framework

ionic framework is support angularjs and cordova both in one package and it is very faster then other framework

```
http://ionicframework.com/
```

just dive me the email address i will send you the basic startup

Comment: I checked it, it sounds good but i want more clarity about using cordova, ionic as you mentioned in answer.

Comment: if you want more help email me i will tell you